# Retrieve query parameters in Python

Tags: python, flask, request

I have a request object which has a header and some query parameters.

I can get the headers parameters like this:

```
request.headers.get('content-type')
```

How can I get the value for query parameter "Subject" in Python?

For example: `http://localhost:5000/api?Subject=Test`

I'm using Flask (flask.pocoo.org) for the servers and Requests (docs.python-requests.org/en/master) for the client.

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information. Python itself does not know anything about receiving web requests, so you must be using some kind of framework. Which?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/  Flask for the servers
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ Requests for the client